# how add description tag for page

Tags: wordpress

How to add description tag for my self hosting wordpress blog. Even though am using SEO Yoast, but I could not find this option. Am getting problem to add description for this page, for example,

```
http://sitename/author/authname/page/10/
http://sitename/author/tag/tagname/page/1
```

I don't know how to and where to add description for this pages,because there is no such page. But my SEO plugin says that description is missing in these pages [not only these in all similar pages.]

Comment: Where does it say that description is missing?

Comment: Am using godaddy SEO optimization tool, In that, it shows as high alert. That's why need to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this description really means **Meta description**. Check if your pages / posts contain this information.

In SEO Yoast, the Meta description is located in general meta box when editing posts, pages.

Look at the first image in [ScreenShots Tab](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/screenshots/) of WordPress Plugin Page.

**UPDATE:**

Using SEO Yoast you can also set Meta description for the home page. You do that by going to **Dashboard > SEO > Titles & Metas** and select **Home tab**. There you will find **Meta description template:**.

Comment: Yes, That meta description is for that post only. But not for the pages. The pages contain around 10 post, for example if we have 100 post and 10 post to display per page. Each page will have 10 post, so pages will be named as page1, page2, page3... page10, in that page only am getting meta description missing error,    http://sitename/author/authname/page/10/

Comment: You probably do not have set meta description for the home page (page that lists your posts). Check the UPDATE of my answer how to add that.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I have updated it.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please take a moment and accept it by clicking on the big checkbox located on the left of this answer.